# Query to join three tables With Sum

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sum

I am trying to join thee tables and there's one Sum value but its not showing any error but its a wrong value... but if I join with two table it working correctly.

the query is

```
SELECT  tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, 
        SUM(tblLeave.lvDay) AS Total, 
        tblAtData.card_no

FROM    tblEmployeeInfo 
INNER JOIN tblLeave ON tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode = tblLeave.lvEmpId 
INNER JOIN tblAtData ON tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCardID = tblAtData.card_no

WHERE  (tblLeave.lvMonth = @month)

GROUP BY tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, tblAtData.card_no
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate SUM in the subquery for `tblLeave` and then JOIN tables:

```
  SELECT   tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, 
            tblLeave.SUMlvDays AS Total, 
            tblAtData.card_no

    FROM    tblEmployeeInfo 
    INNER JOIN 
        (select lvEmpId, SUM(lvDay) as SUMlvDays 
                    from  tblLeave 
          WHERE  (tblLeave.lvMonth = @month)
         group by lvEmpId )  tblLeave

           ON   tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode = tblLeave.lvEmpId 

    INNER JOIN tblAtData ON tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCardID = tblAtData.card_no
    GROUP BY tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, tblAtData.card_no
```

Comment: Its Working thank-you very-much valex.... Just add "tblLeave.SUMlvDays" in Group by...
Thanx..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, 
        tblLeave.SUMlvDays AS Total, 
        tblAtData.card_no

FROM    tblEmployeeInfo 
INNER JOIN 
    (select lvEmpId, SUM(lvDay) as SUMlvDays 
                from  tblLeave 
      WHERE  (tblLeave.lvMonth = @month)
     group by lvEmpId )  tblLeave

       ON   tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode = tblLeave.lvEmpId 

INNER JOIN tblAtData ON tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCardID = tblAtData.card_no
GROUP BY tblEmployeeInfo.EmpCode, tblAtData.card_no,tblLeave.SUMlvDays
```